# Has Wi-Fi hacking gotten almost impossible?

Tags: passwords, wifi, wpa2, wep, wps

I have read about Wi-Fi password cracking for a while and used different tools my self, such as:

- Airodump for monitoring
- Aicrack for getting key from cap files for WEP/WPA/WPA2
- Reaver for WPS
- Bully for WPS
- Reaver and bully with PixieWPS for WPS

I have tried the tools on WEP, WPA and WPA2, where only WEP is able to get cracked. The weak point of routers was WPS, but reaver and bully seems outdated and I have not gotten them to work on a single router yet. WPA2 cannot be cracked as far as I have understood, and the only way to actually get a password from WPA/WPA2 is by having a word list, which in itself is an extremely bad solution. There is an incredibly low chance of a password being in a word list, and if we talk outside the USA, they are non existant. Since WPS cracking seems to be secured, WPA/WP2 not being able to be cracked without word lists and WPA3 on the way, would that mean that currently Wi-Fi with WPA/WPA2 protection is most likely impossible to hack?

Comment: Try to social engineer using fluxion

Comment: You don't _need_ a wordlist to crack WPA(2). While a wordlist may be quicker, you can also try to bruteforce every possible combination. But you are correct that with a strong, unique password, the odds of cracking it are slim within a reasonable time frame.

Comment: *"There is an __incredibly low chance__ of a password being in a word list, and if we talk outside the USA, they are __non existant__."* - this is a claim without proof and I very much doubt it. Since this unproven claim is a major argument of the question I've downvoted the question.

Answer (score 4):

Having a dictionary password is a norm, not an exception. As for countries other than US, the attacker would simply use password dictionaries for the appropriate locations. Also don’t take term “dictionary attack” too literally: each word is usually passed through some substitutions, so if original word list has the word “Andrew” words like “@ndr3w” or “Andrew1978” would also be checked.

And lastly, just because certain tools aren’t able to preform the attack doesn’t mean you’re secure. The whole WiFi stack is really complex and presents a large attack surface. Vulnerabilities in WPA2 do exist, for recent example check out [KRACK attack](https://www.krackattacks.com).